# NuGet package for linux and windows alike

Tags: linux, windows, nuget, visual-studio-2022

I'm using the nuget package `net.ibm.data.db2` (->windows), which is also available as `net.ibm.data.db2-lnx` (->linux).
Now when building my own .Net 6 project MyProj.csproj in VS 2022 using `net.ibm.data.db2(or -lnx)`, I can simply choose which one to use depending on build configuration:

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug-Linux' OR '$(Configuration)'=='Release-Linux'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="net.ibm.data.db2-lnx" Version="6.0.0.200">
        <PrivateAssets>none</PrivateAssets>
      </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="net.ibm.data.db2" Version="6.0.0.200">
        <PrivateAssets>none</PrivateAssets>
      </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

But when I pack my project it has *only one dependency* to the chosen build configuration upon packing. Either the windows package *or* the linux package.

-> If I want to reference this package somewhere else I have to create a package MyProj and MyProj-lnx to let others use my package for windows and linux.

And if they want to create a package, they have to provide a windows and a linux package as well. And so on.

How can I make one package that contains both versions and chooses the right one, depending on build configuration or sth else I can configure? I want to provide one myproj.nupkg for my clients with windows and linux assemblies for build and publish so they don't have to differ or choose anything.

It's ok to assume that all clients got the `Debug-Linux` and `Release-Linux` configurations

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by using a nuget package that contains both dlls and copies the right one to the output directory. I do not need to directy reference it, it's only used during runtime.

```
nugetpkg:
lib -> no file
contentfiles -> both dll files
buildTransitive -> my_copydll.targets
```

my_copydll.targets contains a condition depending on the used build config ("Release" or "Release-Linux") or the operating system this is being build on. Depending on that, I either copy dll1 or dll2 to the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

I notice the dll file name of them are same and the APIs seems also same.

So I have an idea for your requirements. You can based on dll file instead of package manager.

First you can run the nuget command in your project root directory:

```
nuget install Net.IBM.Data.Db2
nuget install Net.IBM.Data.Db2-lnx
```

Then add the content you need to the project reference like this:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">
    <Reference Include="windows_package_path\IBM.Data.Db2.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Linux'">
    <Reference Include="linux_package_path\IBM.Data.Db2.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Property "OS" will get the current System Type, Windows OS will get "Windows_NT", Linux OS will get "Linux".

Comment: This unfortunately does not solve the problem: When building a nuget package from that project only one db-package is referenced, depending on the packing platform